# Why can't I get a screen resolution higher than 1024x768

Tags: 13.04, resolution, screen, xrandr

I recently built a computer and instead of putting windows 7 on it I put Ubuntu 13.04.

I'm too cheap to buy a graphics card so, I'm using my built-in Intel G41 and the only screen resolution I can get is 1024x768. I need a resolution of 1360x768. I've tried just about everything. I've tried everything from `xrandr` in terminal to ARandR from the software centre. I'm starting to get a little frustrated because I switched to Ubuntu for the simplicity of it all.
this is what I get when I type `xrandr` in Terminal:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1024 x 768, maximum 32767 x 32767
VGA1 connected 1024x768+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 0mm x 0mm
   1024x768       60.0* 
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   848x480        60.0  
   640x480        59.9  
  1280x1024_60.00 (0x252)  109.0MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock   63.7KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1027 end 1034 total 1063           clock   59.9Hz
  1360x768_60.00 (0x257)   84.8MHz
        h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock   47.7KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock   59.8Hz
```

But, When I type `xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1366x768_60_new` it says:

```
xrandr: cannot find output "VGA-1"
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

EDITED: I just saw this typo on your question, it was VGA1 not VGA-1 in your command line, retry and let me know ;)

it seems that your problem was somehow common [Like here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1455942)

The thing I would suggest is to download the latest Ubuntu driver of your express chip-set from the Intel website [G41 Download Page](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/SearchResult.aspx?lang=eng&ProductFamily=Graphics&ProductLine=Desktop%20graphics%20drivers&ProductProduct=Intel%C2%AE%20G41%20Express%20Chipset)

Comment: I tired that but, to be completely honest I have no clue how to install drivers on ubuntu. I've looked on the web and somehow I always get confused or mixed up and just end up making things worse. Could you tell me how to do it like, step-by-step? Or link me to a youtube video or something?

Comment: No Problem ;) Download the driver (either 32-64 bit based on your OS) from [link](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads/2013/intelr-linux-graphics-installer-version-1.0.1), then go to terminal install the debian package with this command : "sudo dpkg -i yourDownloadedPackage.deb"

Comment: Then install the "sudo apt-get install mesa-utils" and then run the command "glxinfo" and let me know the results ;)